# Class III device

Tags: compliance

Does anyone know about a Class III device that is marked with the attached class III symbol?

Thanks.

[image: Class III Symbol]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can decern from a little research. It refers to medical devices that can either kill you or cure you. Pacemakers, defibrillators and devices that can be implanted in the body.

Comment: Do rechargeable battery-operated lab devices like Electronics Pipettes & Electronic Pipette Controllers would fall under the same Class III category or not?

Comment: Please note that I am referring to the appliance classes & not the medical device classes.